# Adding a "Fax Number" when adding a new contact in my iPhone 5, ios6

Tags: ios, contacts

When adding a new contact, I"m confused when I get to the "phone contact numbers".

I only see **Mobile** and **Home**.  I want to add a fax number, but it isn't available and it isn't offered in *Add another field*.

Answer (score 2):

On your contact, click on the label type :

[image]

And it will give you access to the label types.

These are iOS 7 screens, but it's the same on older versions !